# Using Spring boot starters in regular Spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

There is any chance to use spring-boot-starters in regular spring project? I have, big trouble with configuration Spring Social project. I've already configured many others things and I don't want to move my project to Spring Boot just for one library.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

There is any possibility to use Spring Boot goods in regular Spring project? I'm quite confused about Spring Boot, as I read that project helps to quick start project on Spring without making many configs, there are some other pros against regular Spring Project?

But my main question in this thread is: "how to use spring-boot-starters in regular spring project?"

Answer (score 1):

There is independent project (I can't put more than 2 links, so, others you can find in comment):

http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/

And there is a spring social quick start, which will help you to start with it:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-quickstart

spring-social-starter have only maven dependencies. For example, spring-boot-starter-social-facebook contains this in pom.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

You can add this without dependencies from org.springframework.boot package in your pom for using it without spring-boot functionality.

Comment: +two projects:
http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-linkedin/
http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/

Comment: I know there is standalone spring social project, but it need some configuration in contrast to spring-social-starter

Thank you for link to example config, I will try this :)

Comment: As I see, spring-social-starter - it's just a pom-file with dependencies: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-social-facebook/pom.xml
You can copy this dependencies to your project and it will be the same.